# Building a web front end from an existing API

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I'm building a front end web application from an existing (RESTful) API.

What is the best way to go about this? I'm assuming the new standard way to do this is through something like backbone.js.

I also want the pages to be different URL's and not have a single page application. That said,  I'm guessing it's bad practice to request the page and then fire off async api requests when we might as well load the data from the server to start, right? What sort of architecture or technology should I be looking at so that I can reuse the API but not send off two requests to the server back to back, one to load the page, and one to load the data?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone and other JavaScript "MV*" frameworks are definitely a great choice for performant event-driven UIs. You can use this design and have different pages and URLs. It just makes it easier and faster to do the asynch operations on a given page because you will have the relevant data in a JSON model and use a pub / sub pattern in an environment where views automatically update when data changes. Another advantage of this type of design is that you can have your data in models as opposed to walking the DOM to get data.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Girardi's answer, your concern about doing two request on initial page load - one for the page and one for the actual data - is a real problem.

One of the solutions is to bootstrap the initial data right into the page so you can skip the additional async request. This is called Model Bootstrapping. For example, you can place and additional `<script></script>` tag which will holds the bootstrapped model:

```
<script>
    window.I_MODEL = [
        {id: 1, name: "foo"},
        {id: 2, name: "bar"}
    ]
</script>
```

then construct your model on the server side and with the help of some templating mechanism print the serialized model right into the page.

Search for backbone model bootstrapping, here is a right-to-the-point example: http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#bootstrapping_data

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is definitely what I would do normally for this type of thing, however, I am working off an already built API on the same server and don't want to duplicate code for the initial data set. I wasn't sure if it was a known practice to call the API class's separately from the API controller in my web app controller. Even then, the API controller could be altering things before JSON return so I am not guaranteed similar output. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I prefer because my web services are only wrappers around the business layer meth. and never altering the data they get, so in my case it's safe to call them directly, their output will be the same. I'm not familiar with your environment and I have no idea what can or cannot be guaranteed in your backend, but what about this scenario: you have 2 REST services, the one which gives the JSON and the one which produces the webpage. When somebody requests the webpage, before you're returning it just call the other service which responds with the JSON. Take that response and render it into the page.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's not a bad practice to load page first and then requesting async data. keeping template(html) and data calls separate, you can exploit benefits of localStorage, browserCaching to maximum extent. Backbone doesn't inject any magic into your application, it's just provides a framework to organise your code and helps in avoiding some boilerplate code again and again.

Comment: I would argue that it is bad practice to always have 2 (or more) requests. It might be practice, but that doesn't make it good practice.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen every approach has pros and cons. If I want to cache template for feature use having them separate will always help you. Well, concatenation and minimising number of requests are good, but if you have an application of gmail/facebook size, it's not practical.

Comment: You're right, this is a perfectly plausible solution for something like facebook. However, I'm working off of the assumption that it is not for this application because I'm not working with facebook sized data, and for my application, it would be a waste of time.